# Will server side redirect for mobile devices satisfy google?

Tags: seo, mobile, googlebot-mobile

Because our client base is largely government agencies, we have been way behind on mobile support for our site. Now with google making mobile readiness a core part of their search rankings, it is suddenly a priority.

A truly responsive design would require a complete redesign, which in all honestly is desirable anyway, but it is proving to be a tough sell, and management wants to leave the existing desktop-oriented site as-is and use redirects to host completely separate versions of our pages for mobile users.

Before I dig my heels in and fight for the more time consuming responsive redesign, is there a concrete SEO advantage to either approach?

Answer (score 0):

Too many redirects will give you issues with google, heres a video by matt cutts discussing any issues

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1lVPrYoBkA

He specifically mentions 4-5 chained redirects

Comment: I would assume that a redirect to a separate mobile site could be done with just one redirect.  I wouldn't expect to run into chain of redirects problems when redirecting to mobile.